# C# Static cast char to string

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, character, string-concatenation

I am trying to declare a constant char to hold a key and a constant string to hold a message telling the user to press the key:

```
...
private const KEY = 'r';
private const string MSG = "Press " + KEY + " to restart.";
...
```

I need to explicitly cast the key char to a string since the implicit cast is done during runtime. However, I can't figure out the way to cast a character to a string at compile time. I've seen ToString () on the internet, but it's performed at runtime and therefore doesn't work. I have the key char as a separate variable because it is used several times in the program. Does anybody know how to statically cast a char to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't compose a `string` with anything other than `string` fragments.

You have a few options though. You can make both constants `string` types:

```
private const string KEY = "r";
private const string MSG = "Press " + KEY + " to restart.";
```

Another option would be to compose the `string` at runtime:

```
private const char KEY = 'r';
private static string MSG => "Press " + KEY + " to restart.";
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid this initially, but I ended up needing it converted to a string every time I needed it, so it makes sense to store it as a string

Answer (score 1):

You can't `const string` with other values which is `const`.

You can try to use `readonly`.

`readonly` can only modify values ​in the class constructor method, it will set that value at runtime.

```
private const char KEY = 'r';
private readonly string MSG = "Press " + KEY + " to restart.";
```

Comment: Thank you, that would work, but I'm going with davidg's suggestion to change the char to be a string because I ended up only ever needing it as a string. I'll be sure to remember both ways in the future though